# C File input & output

Tags: c, file-io

I made a simple dictionary code, and surfed for an hour, and I found a file I/O code. But my compiler(I use Microsoft visual C++) says my code(unfortunately, the core part of the code) is wrong. but I can't get it. What is actually wrong and why???

```
    /*
     DosDic ver 1.0.0 2015-07-03
    */




    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>




    char key = 0;                         
    FILE *fp;                             //set a file pointer var 
    fp = fopen("dicdata.dat","r");        //open a file
    int b = 0;
    int trial = 0;
    char result[];
    char searchfor[] = fp;                //save a whole list of dictionary in a var
    int i;
     char sb[];                            //var for search in a list
    int getsearchtrial(char sb[]){
        for(i=0;i=strlen(sb);i++){        //how much I tried to reach to the word
            switch((int)searchfor[b]-(int)sb[i]){  //are two alphabets same?
            case 0 :
            default : i=0;               
            }
        b++;                               //keep finding in a list
        trial++;                           //try again
        }
    return trial;                         
    }
    int adress;
    int mainpage(){
        printf("Type what you want to search : ");
        scanf("%c",sb[ ]);
        getsearchtrial(sb[ ]) - strlen(sb[ ]) = adress;  //where the word is located in the list
        for(i = adress;i = adress + 30; i++){  //print
            printf("%c",searchfor[i]);
        }
        printf("Thank you for using DosDic ver.1.0!"); //thank you!
    }
    void main(){                  //call all those functions
        mainpage();
        fclose(fp);           //close list
    }

    //and whats wrong with this? i cant even get it, but it's not working
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? What does your compiler tell you? What are the exact errors/warnings?

Comment: We need compiler errors/warnings and/or expected and actual output to help you out

Answer (score 3):

Multiple issues.

First of all, you can't assign the result of `fopen` to `fp` outside the body of a function; you must move `fp = fopen("dicdata.dat", "r");` to within the body of one of your functions (`getsearchtrial` most likely).

Secondly, you don't read from a file by simply assigning a file pointer to an object; you must use a library function like `fscanf` or `fread` or `fgets`. Assuming your file contains a single string of length 80, you'd need to write something like

```
char searchfor[81] = {0}; // make sure string is initially empty,
                          // extra space for string terminator

if ( !fgets( searchfor, sizeof searchfor, fp) )
{
  // error reading from file
}
```

Of course, this depends on how your input file is structured.  If it contains a list of strings, then you'll need to use a multidimensional array (or some other structure).

Third, when you declare an array, must specify its size before you can use it.  `result` and `searchfor` are *incomplete* array definitions.

Finally, this line

```
getsearchtrial(sb[ ]) - strlen(sb[ ]) = adress;
```

needs to be reversed; the target of an assignment *must* be on the left of the assignment operator.

You need to step back and learn how to write C code from the ground up.

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong I'm not even going to itemise it all here - most of it seems to stem from your lack of understanding of arrays in C.

Most notably...

- You can't declare an array and not initialise it or specify a size.
- You can't assign a `FILE *` to a `char` array (and expect decent
  results).
- You can't execute a statement like `fp = fopen` at the
  global scope like you are.

Try [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) and you may fix 95% of your problems, then go from there.